# EJB: What is remote client?

Tags: ejb, client

I am going through EJB specification(ejb-3_1-pfd-spec). I am not able to completely grasp concept of remote client:
Spec document states following:

"The interface used by a remote client of a session bean is implemented by the container as a remote business interface (or a remote EJBObject interface), and the remote client view of a session bean is location-independent. A client running in the same JVM as the session object uses the same API as a client running in a different JVM on the same or different machine"

This suggests that remote client can run in same JVM or different JVM from session object.
But different discussion threads suggest that a remote client is one which runs in JVM different from session bean.

So which definition is more accurate.

Any guidance would be of great value.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit reflexive - a remote client on JVM A on machine A is connecting through to an EJB component on JVM B on machine B, that's all either side is aware of.  In some situations, it may be that machine A and machine B are the same machine.  It may also happen that JVM A and JVM B are the same JVM.

The important thing is that remote clients are location agnostic - they must behave the same regardless of where they are on the network.  As a programmer, this means your code must not assume they are in the same place.  As a deployer, it means that you can choose to deploy them on one machine or on several, without any code changes.